# How to read specific value against particular key in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My code is as show below:

```
        mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference();

        mFirebaseDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                allText.setText(dataSnapshot.child("58ca237b2e2c211dc0c7ed9").child("order_status").getValue(String.class));
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + dataSnapshot.hasChild("58ca237b2e2c211dc0c7ed9"));
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: next " + dataSnapshot.getValue().equals("58ca237b2e2c211dc0c7ed9"));
                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange for: " + child.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled: ");
            }
        });
```

The response that I am getting in log is as shown below:

```
onDataChange for: DataSnapshot { key = 58ca237b2e2c211dc0c7ed9, value = {order_status=2} }
```

Here, I want to read `order_status=2`, but I am unable to do it. How can I do that?

My firebase schema is as show below:

[image: firebase schema]

Comment: create a model of what type of data you are expecting and then you can simply read that using that model

Answer (score 0):

Create Model of result that you are expecting and then simply do like this, you can manipulate the code that works for you

```
public static class Post {

public String author;
public String title;

public Post(String author, String title) {
 this.author = author;
 this.title = title;
}

//Default Constructor
public Post {
}

//Setter and Getter below
 -----
```

// Get a reference to our posts

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("server/saving-
data/fireblog/posts");
```

// Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
    System.out.println(post.get(------));
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
}
});
```

Comment: Can you look at the schema and tell me that how can I get order_status?

Comment: model type will be string order_status

Comment: Just get reference to node that you wanna listen to and then simple using above model demo to get data

Answer (score 0):

You can Send/Receive Data from FireBase following way:

**Send data to FireBase**

```
EmpInfo empInfo = new EmpInfo();
                empInfo.setName(mEditTextName.getText().toString());
                empInfo.setAge(mEditTextAge.getText().toString());
                empInfo.setMobile(mEditTextMobileNo.getText().toString());
                empInfo.setCity(autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString());

                databaseReference.child("Emp_Info").setValue(empInfo);
```

**Get Data from FireBase**

```
databaseReference.child("Emp_Info").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d(TAG,"onDataChages invoked ="+dataSnapshot.toString());

                    //Getting the data from snapshot
                    EmpInfo empInfo = (EmpInfo)dataSnapshot.getValue(EmpInfo.class);
                    mTextName.setText(mTextName.getText()+" : "+empInfo.getName());
                    mTextAge.setText(mTextAge.getText()+" : "+empInfo.getAge());
                    mTextMobileNo.setText(mTextMobileNo.getText()+" : "+empInfo.getMobile());
                    mTextCity.setText(mTextCity.getText()+" : "+empInfo.getCity());


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

**Model class**

```
public class EmpInfo {
    public String name;
    public String age;
    public String mobile;
    public String city;

    public EmpInfo(){

    }

    public EmpInfo(String name, String age, String mobile,String city) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

Hope It will help you !

Comment: Can you look at the schema and tell me that how can I get order_status?

Comment: @MrugeshThaker you can simply do databaseReference.child("58ca237b2e2c211dc0c7ed9").addValueEventListener(){}

Comment: @MrugeshThaker in side loop in your code child.child("order_status").getValue()